# Library to generate heat map map overlay based off point values not point densities

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, heatmap

I have a set of data points where each point is expressed as a lat/lng.  Each of these points has a value associated with it that changes over time.  I would like to produce a heatmap animation overlay on top of a map that reflects this change in value over time.  Note: I am fine with producing a series of static "snapshots" and piecing them together frame-by-frame into an animation, so the heatmap library itself does not have to support animation.

My first attempt was to use the [HeatMapLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#HeatmapLayer) which is a part of the Google Maps visualization library. However as per the question [*Heatmap based on average weights and not on the number of data points*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14461954/129475), it would seem that this particular visualization library insists on weighing the *density* of points in determining what color to use surrounding a given point.

I am after a solution that only considers the value of the points rather than the density.  To give an example, assume one wanted to visualize the ambient temperature of a city over time, but there were more thermometers installed in some parts of the city than others.  You wouldn't want a small area with many thermometers installed to show up red just because there were many thermometers - you'd want it to show up red only if it was hot there.

Basically, I want a single color for each of my points that reflects the intensity of the point's value, and then a gradient spatial transition between any two point's colors.  It doesn't have to be Google Maps - the key criteria is just `i)` must base colors off point values not point densities `ii)` must overlay on top of a map and `iii)` ideally has a programming abstraction that talks in terms of lat/lng's, rather than requiring manual conversion to e.g. Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

[global temps](https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/69265940_2449044035161173_3255016101431476224_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_oc=AQkmjn928C_7XJVZJYOdUvFlJyqEO0rM6kdRizJVvBZo-E2ag-QfXWDvAnS5f3mQCXSa6BTYNE-lOA_2GxfUmIUM&_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.xx&oh=a39cd4d2f9f393deae5e7765400cd592&oe=5DD1D158)You can do this with multiple:

gmaps.symbol_layer

and then just layer them up:

fig_gmap.add_layer(red_markers)

fig_gmap.add_layer(yellow_markers)

fig_gmap.add_layer(green_markers)

fig_gmap.add_layer(blue_markers)

I haven't been able to successfully pass a value that gives me a good temp color for the heat maps, just always get some variation on the density thing, which is a one trick pony.  It would be nice having a way to do this and animate the marker icon without java.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/). It has a plugin for Google Maps: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/plugin-gmaps-layer.html

This library uses datasets made of coordinates and values. I think it will behave the way you described.